# Problema en Switch-Case

Tags: java

No se si ya hay un post sobre esto, estoy intentando hacer un Menu que es bastante básico utilizando el ya mencionado **Switch-Case**.
Tengo un error el cual es que la opción 2 debo añadir un jugador a un equipo, el equipo es creado en la opción 1, el problema es que al no inicializar el equipo en la misma condición no me deja ejecutarlo. !!!Ayuda¡¡¡

Adjunto el codigo que llevo hasta ahora.

```
package presentacion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import dominio.Equipo;
import dominio.persona.Jugador;

public class Menu {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void mostrar() {

        List<Equipo> equipos = new ArrayList<Equipo>();

        String menu = "Bienvenido al Sistema\n"
                + "Ingrese 1 para agregar un Equipo\n"
                + "Ingrese 2 para agregar un Jugador a un Equipo\n"
                + "Ingrese 3 para borrar un Jugador de un Equipo\n"
                + "Ingrese 4 para mostrar la informacion de todos los Equipos\n"
                + "Ingrese 0 para salir del sistema";

        int opcion = 0;

        do {
            opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menu));

            switch(opcion) {

                case 1 :
                    Equipo equipo = new Equipo();
                    equipo.cargarDatos();
                    equipos.add(equipo);
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    String agregarJugador = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del Equipo al cual desea agregar un Jugador\n"
                            + "Lista de los Equipos disponibles: \n"
                            + equipos);
                    int confirJugador = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Seguro que quiere agregar un jugador a este equipo?");
                    while(confirJugador == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                        Jugador jugador = new Jugador();
                        jugador.cargarDatos();
                        equipo.addJugador(jugador);
                        confirJugador = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Desea agregar otro Jugador?");
                    }   
                    break;
                case 3 :

                    break;
                case 4 :
                    for(Equipo e : equipos) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    }
                    break;
                case 0 :
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saliendo de la aplicacion..."); 
                    break;
            }
        }while(opcion != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes revisar el contenido de `equipos` (o su longitud, etc.) para saber si ya se inicializó un equipo al menos...

Comment: Creo que necesitas una variable en la clase Menu. Sería una variable Equipo, yo le llamaría private Equipo equipoSeleccionado. Y setearlo en el case 1: y utilizarlo en el case 2

Answer (score 0):

Pondría una variable para saber de que equipo estamos hablando...

```
public class Menu {
    private Equipo equipoSeleccionado = null;
```

Luego agregaría un método para seleccionar el equipo:

```
private void seleccionaEquipo() {
     Equipo equipo = new Equipo();
     equipo.cargarDatos();
     equipos.add(equipo);
     equipoSeleccionado = equipo;
}
```

luego ya cambiaría 2 de los cases:

```
 case 1 :
     seleccionaEquipo();
     break;

 case 2 :
     if (equipoSeleccionadoo == null) {
         seleccionaEquipo();
     }
     /*
         Entonces ya tengo el equipo al que se le va agregar el jugador
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

en el case 2 primero deberias verificar si por lo menos hay un registro de equipos, si es asi agrega el jugador, caso contrario informar que no hay equipo y debe crear primero el equipo, asi le haría yo:

```
case 2 :
   if(equipos.size()>0){
      String agregarJugador = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del Equipo al cual desea agregar un Jugador\n"
                        + "Lista de los Equipos disponibles: \n"
                        + equipos);
                int confirJugador = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Seguro que quiere agregar un jugador a este equipo?");
                while(confirJugador == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    Jugador jugador = new Jugador();
                    jugador.cargarDatos();
                    equipo.addJugador(jugador);
                    confirJugador = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Desea agregar otro Jugador?");
                } 
   }else{
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Debe crear al menos un equipo antes de crear un jugador");
   }  
                break;
```